# How to design a MVC 4 Project to cater for Url Re-writing and Different Platforms/Browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mobile, url-rewriting

I'm looking to create a MVC 4 project that needs to be able to support both URL rewriting and the ability to return and render different views depending on the device e.g a Desktop PC, Mobile Phone or Tablet.

For example;

**URL REWRITING**

Basically for each View instead of it being Product (with a ID passed to show the data), I'd like the URL to read something like www.mydomain.com/my-product-name/ instead of www.mydomain.com/ProductView/?Id=12345

**RESPONSIVE MOBILE DESIGN**

So when visiting the page www.mydomain.com/my-product-name/ I want the view returned to be that which is designed to run on a Desktop browser if that was the client request.  Or if on a mobile phone, the cut down basic view.

Can anyone offer any examples or useful docs to refer to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you haven't done much reading on MVC4 at all, since the things you mention are key features of MVC4.

First, MVC4 does not need URL rewriting.  It uses friendly url's out of the box like you want, no rewriting necessary.

Second, MVC4 uses mobile templating that allows you to define different views for different mobile devices, and it will automatically select the correct view based on the device that views it.

I suggest you read this:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

Comment: Correct, I'm very new to MVC

Answer (score 0):

**1. For Friendly URLS:**

No need for Url-Rewriting, a `Route` should be enough:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductPage", // Route Name
    "{product*}", // Url Pattern
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Info", product = UrlParameter.Optional},
);
```

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

**2. For custom Views per device:**

MVC 4 introduced `Display Mode Provider` that lets you determine the View file to use based on any criteria you choose to extract from the HTTP Request, for example:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("iPad")
    {
    ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.UserAgent.Contains("ipad"))
    });
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296507.aspx